# Best Eclipse UML plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml

for Reverse engineering I need to create class , sequence, usecase,deployment diagram so Which is the best uml modeling plugin for eclipse?

Comment: UMLet is pretty cool and light

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For my projects I used [ObjectAid](http://www.objectaid.com/). It is also free so that's a bonus. Hope it helps.

Comment: Today seems like it needs purchased license after a period of evaluation.

Comment: Its not freewere, please find the below url about licence. http://www.objectaid.com/products

Comment: some of the features are free, some other paid for, for my needs was enough as i just wanted to visualize the whole architecture of my project

Answer (score 29):

You should take a look at Papyrus which is an official Eclipse Project: http://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/